# Apache: difference virtualhost and htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I set up a private server (raspberry) with apache.
the config file for the website:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName me.example.com
    ServerAlias me.example.com
        RewriteEngine On
#only rewrite if not one of the followed files is requested
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/.*\.(jpg|ico|png|mp4|ogg)
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/.*\.css
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/.*\.js
#rewrite all requests to index.php and get path (only intern)
        RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/(.*)$ /index.php?lang=$1&path=$2 [NC]

DocumentRoot /var/www/my/root
    <Directory /var/www/my/root>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            Options -Indexes
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

1.) If I request now a "subpage" like /impressum.php. It will show me the impressum, instead of rewriting to the index file. Why?

2.) Now I copied the part of the rewrite engine into a .htaccess file and it doesn't work anymore. Where is the difference between these two files? What do I need to change, so it will work?
My .htaccess file looks like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
#only rewrite if not one of the followed files is requested
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/.*\.(jpg|ico|png|mp4|ogg)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/.*\.css
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/.*\.js
#rewrite all requests to index.php and get path (only intern)
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/(.*)$ /index.php?lang=$1&path=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: this line:
    RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/(.*)$ /index.php?lang=$1&path=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
needs to be edited to:
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)$ /index.php?lang=$1&path=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
(The first slash is away). Now the concept works again. Last problem:
just the main topics work: so if i call me.example.com/de/test it works. If i try to reach: me.example.com/de/test/subtheme. It redirects me to the main page instead of the existend subpage!

Answer (score 0):

the files were missing ... so it redirected to the home.
It works better then me